How can I display small black and white images on a e-paper spi display with a Raspberry Pi Pico W?
I have purchases a Raspberry Pi Pico W and have wired it to the Waveshare 1.54 inch e-Paper display module V2 I have used the code available at the github page, specifically the epd1in54b.py and the epconfig.py,
The specific errors that I have got are some missing libraries, including logging, spidev, ctypes, subprocess. I have tried to work around this as best as I can by replacing these modules with modules supported by Micropython & the Raspberry Pi Pico W.
This is the modified version of epd1in54b_V2.py file
import epdconfig

# Display resolution
EPD_WIDTH = 200
EPD_HEIGHT = 200

class EPD:
    def __init__(self, cs, dc, rst, busy):
        self.reset_pin = rst
        self.dc_pin = dc
        self.busy_pin = busy
        self.cs_pin = cs
        self.width = EPD_WIDTH
        self.height = EPD_HEIGHT

    # Hardware reset
    def reset(self):
        epdconfig.digital_write(self.reset_pin, 1)
        epdconfig.delay_ms(200)
        epdconfig.digital_write(self.reset_pin, 0)  # module reset
        epdconfig.delay_ms(5)
        epdconfig.digital_write(self.reset_pin, 1)
        epdconfig.delay_ms(200)

    def send_command(self, command):
        epdconfig.digital_write(self.dc_pin, 0)
        epdconfig.digital_write(self.cs_pin, 0)
        epdconfig.spi_writebyte([command])  # Ensure this sends a list
        epdconfig.digital_write(self.cs_pin, 1)

    def send_data(self, data):
        epdconfig.digital_write(self.dc_pin, 1)
        epdconfig.digital_write(self.cs_pin, 0)
        epdconfig.spi_writebyte([data])  # Ensure this sends a list
        epdconfig.digital_write(self.cs_pin, 1)

    # Send a lot of data
    def send_data2(self, data):
        epdconfig.digital_write(self.dc_pin, 1)
        epdconfig.digital_write(self.cs_pin, 0)
        epdconfig.spi_writebyte2(data)  # Pass the data array directly
        epdconfig.digital_write(self.cs_pin, 1)

    def ReadBusy(self):
        print("e-Paper busy")
        while epdconfig.digital_read(self.busy_pin) == 1:
            epdconfig.delay_ms(100)
        print("e-Paper busy release")

    def init(self):
        if epdconfig.module_init() != 0:
            return -1
        # EPD hardware init start
        self.reset()

        self.ReadBusy()
        self.send_command(0x12)  # SWRESET
        self.ReadBusy()

        self.send_command(0x01)  # Driver output control
        self.send_data(0xC7)
        self.send_data(0x00)
        self.send_data(0x01)

        self.send_command(0x11)  # Data entry mode
        self.send_data(0x01)

        self.send_command(0x44)  # Set RAM-X address start/end position
        self.send_data(0x00)
        self.send_data(0x18)  # 0x18 --> (24+1)*8=200

        self.send_command(0x45)  # Set RAM-Y address start/end position
        self.send_data(0xC7)  # 0xC7 --> (199+1)=200
        self.send_data(0x00)
        self.send_data(0x00)
        self.send_data(0x00)

        self.send_command(0x3C)  # BorderWaveform
        self.send_data(0x05)

        self.send_command(0x18)  # Read built-in temperature sensor
        self.send_data(0x80)

        self.send_command(0x4E)  # Set RAM x address count to 0
        self.send_data(0x00)
        self.send_command(0x4F)  # Set RAM y address count to 0X199
        self.send_data(0xC7)
        self.send_data(0x00)
        self.ReadBusy()
        return 0

    def getbuffer(self, image):
        buf = [0xFF] * int(self.width * self.height / 8)
        image_monocolor = image.convert('1')
        imwidth, imheight = image_monocolor.size
        if imwidth != self.width or imheight != self.height:
            raise ValueError('Image must be same dimensions as display ({0}x{1}).'.format(self.width, self.height))

        pixels = image_monocolor.load()
        for y in range(self.height):
            for x in range(self.width):
                if pixels[x, y] == 0:
                    buf[int((x + y * self.width) / 8)] &= ~(0x80 >> (x % 8))
        return buf

    def display(self, blackimage, redimage):
        if self.width % 8 == 0:
            linewidth = int(self.width / 8)
        else:
            linewidth = int(self.width / 8) + 1

        buf = [0x00] * self.height * linewidth

        # Send black data
        if blackimage is not None:
            self.send_command(0x24)  # DATA_START_TRANSMISSION_1
            self.send_data2(blackimage)

        # Send red data
        if redimage is not None:
            self.send_command(0x26)  # DATA_START_TRANSMISSION_2
            for i in range(int(self.width * self.height / 8)):
                buf[i] = ~redimage[i]
            self.send_data2(buf)

        self.send_command(0x22)  # DISPLAY_REFRESH
        self.send_data(0xF7)
        self.send_command(0x20)  # DISPLAY_REFRESH
        self.ReadBusy()

    def Clear(self):
        if self.width % 8 == 0:
            linewidth = int(self.width / 8)
        else:
            linewidth = int(self.width / 8) + 1

        self.send_command(0x24)  # DATA_START_TRANSMISSION_1
        self.send_data2([0xff] * int(self.height * linewidth))

        self.send_command(0x26)  # DATA_START_TRANSMISSION_2
        self.send_data2([0x00] * int(self.height * linewidth))

        self.send_command(0x22)  # DISPLAY_REFRESH
        self.send_data(0xF7)
        self.send_command(0x20)  # DISPLAY_REFRESH
        self.ReadBusy()

    def sleep(self):
        self.send_command(0x10)  # Enter deep sleep
        self.send_data(0x01)

        epdconfig.delay_ms(2000)
        epdconfig.module_exit()

The modified epdconfig.py file is here:
import os
import sys
import time

# logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

import machine
import time

class RaspberryPi:
    # Pin definition
    RST_PIN  = 17
    DC_PIN   = 25
    CS_PIN   = 8
    BUSY_PIN = 24
    PWR_PIN  = 18

    def __init__(self):
        self.spi = machine.SPI(0, baudrate=4000000, polarity=0, phase=0, sck=machine.Pin(18), mosi=machine.Pin(19))
        self.rst = machine.Pin(self.RST_PIN, machine.Pin.OUT)
        self.dc = machine.Pin(self.DC_PIN, machine.Pin.OUT)
        self.cs = machine.Pin(self.CS_PIN, machine.Pin.OUT)
        self.busy = machine.Pin(self.BUSY_PIN, machine.Pin.IN)
        self.pwr = machine.Pin(self.PWR_PIN, machine.Pin.OUT)
        
        self.cs(1)  # Disable the chip select

    def digital_write(self, pin, value):
        pin_obj = getattr(self, pin.lower())
        pin_obj.value(value)

    def digital_read(self, pin):
        pin_obj = getattr(self, pin.lower())
        return pin_obj.value()

    def delay_ms(self, delaytime):
        time.sleep_ms(delaytime)

    def spi_writebyte(self, data):
        self.cs(0)  # Enable chip select
        self.spi.write(bytearray(data))
        self.cs(1)  # Disable chip select

    def module_init(self):
        self.pwr.on()
        return 0

    def module_exit(self):
        self.spi.deinit()
        self.rst.off()
        self.dc.off()
        self.pwr.off()
        print("SPI end, Module enters 0 power consumption ...")

# Assuming we are using the RaspberryPi configuration for the Pico
implementation = RaspberryPi()

# Export functions to the module level
for func in [x for x in dir(implementation) if not x.startswith('_')]:
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], func, getattr(implementation, func))
            
            

class JetsonNano:
    # Pin definition
    RST_PIN  = 17
    DC_PIN   = 25
    CS_PIN   = 8
    BUSY_PIN = 24
    PWR_PIN  = 18

    def __init__(self):
        import Jetson.GPIO
        self.GPIO = Jetson.GPIO

    def digital_write(self, pin, value):
        self.GPIO.output(pin, value)

    def digital_read(self, pin):
        return self.GPIO.input(self.BUSY_PIN)

    def delay_ms(self, delaytime):
        time.sleep(delaytime / 1000.0)

    def spi_writebyte(self, data):
        self.SPI.SYSFS_software_spi_transfer(data[0])

    def spi_writebyte2(self, data):
        for i in range(len(data)):
            self.SPI.SYSFS_software_spi_transfer(data[i])

    def module_init(self):
        self.GPIO.setmode(self.GPIO.BCM)
        self.GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        self.GPIO.setup(self.RST_PIN, self.GPIO.OUT)
        self.GPIO.setup(self.DC_PIN, self.GPIO.OUT)
        self.GPIO.setup(self.CS_PIN, self.GPIO.OUT)
        self.GPIO.setup(self.PWR_PIN, self.GPIO.OUT)
        self.GPIO.setup(self.BUSY_PIN, self.GPIO.IN)
        self.GPIO.output(self.PWR_PIN, 1)
        self.SPI.SYSFS_software_spi_begin()
        return 0

    def module_exit(self):
        print("spi end")
        self.SPI.SYSFS_software_spi_end()
        print("close 5V, Module enters 0 power consumption ...")
        self.GPIO.output(self.RST_PIN, 0)
        self.GPIO.output(self.DC_PIN, 0)
        self.GPIO.output(self.PWR_PIN, 0)
        self.GPIO.cleanup([self.RST_PIN, self.DC_PIN, self.CS_PIN, self.BUSY_PIN, self.PWR_PIN])

class SunriseX3:
    # Pin definition
    RST_PIN  = 17
    DC_PIN   = 25
    CS_PIN   = 8
    BUSY_PIN = 24
    PWR_PIN  = 18
    Flag     = 0

    def __init__(self):
        import spidev
        import Hobot.GPIO
        self.GPIO = Hobot.GPIO
        self.SPI = spidev.SpiDev()

    def digital_write(self, pin, value):
        self.GPIO.output(pin, value)

    def digital_read(self, pin):
        return self.GPIO.input(pin)

    def delay_ms(self, delaytime):
        time.sleep(delaytime / 1000.0)

    def spi_writebyte(self, data):
        self.SPI.writebytes(data)

    def spi_writebyte2(self, data):
        self.SPI.xfer3(data)

    def module_init(self):
        if self.Flag == 0:
            self.Flag = 1
            self.GPIO.setmode(self.GPIO.BCM)
            self.GPIO.setwarnings(False)
            self.GPIO.setup(self.RST_PIN, self.GPIO.OUT)
            self.GPIO.setup(self.DC_PIN, self.GPIO.OUT)
            self.GPIO.setup(self.CS_PIN, self.GPIO.OUT)
            self.GPIO.setup(self.PWR_PIN, self.GPIO.OUT)
            self.GPIO.setup(self.BUSY_PIN, self.GPIO.IN)
            self.GPIO.output(self.PWR_PIN, 1)
            self.SPI.open(2, 0)
            self.SPI.max_speed_hz = 4000000
            self.SPI.mode = 0b00
            return 0
        else:
            return 0

    def module_exit(self):
        print("spi end")
        self.SPI.close()
        print("close 5V, Module enters 0 power consumption ...")
        self.Flag = 0
        self.GPIO.output(self.RST_PIN, 0)
        self.GPIO.output(self.DC_PIN, 0)
        self.GPIO.output(self.PWR_PIN, 0)
        self.GPIO.cleanup([self.RST_PIN, self.DC_PIN, self.CS_PIN, self.BUSY_PIN], self.PWR_PIN)

output = "Raspberry Pi Pico"

if "Raspberry" in output:
    implementation = RaspberryPi()
elif os.path.exists('/sys/bus/platform/drivers/gpio-x3'):
    implementation = SunriseX3()
else:
    implementation = JetsonNano()

for func in [x for x in dir(implementation) if not x.startswith('_')]:
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], func, getattr(implementation, func))

### END OF FILE ###

The code I am using to generate the image is here:
import framebuf
import utime
from machine import Pin, SPI
import epd1in54b_V2

# Initialize the SPI communication
spi = SPI(1, baudrate=2000000, polarity=0, phase=0, sck=Pin(10), mosi=Pin(11), miso=Pin(12))

# Initialize the e-paper display
epd = epd1in54b_V2.EPD(spi, cs=Pin(13), dc=Pin(14), rst=Pin(15), busy=Pin(16))

# Clear the display
epd.init()
epd.clear_frame_memory(0xFF)
epd.display_frame()

# Create a black and white image (10x10 pixels)
image_width = 10
image_height = 10
image = bytearray(image_width * image_height // 8)
framebuf_image = framebuf.FrameBuffer(image, image_width, image_height, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)

# Draw a 10x10 pixel black square
for y in range(image_height):
    for x in range(image_width):
        framebuf_image.pixel(x, y, 0)  # 0 means black in MONO_HLSB mode

# Calculate the position to place the image in the center of the display
display_width = epd.width
display_height = epd.height
x_pos = (display_width - image_width) // 2
y_pos = (display_height - image_height) // 2

# Display the image
epd.set_frame_memory(image, x_pos, y_pos, image_width, image_height)
epd.display_frame()

# Put the display to sleep
epd.sleep()

Can someone please advise me on how to do this.
EDIT:
I am using Thonny to connect to my Raspberry Pi Pico W, on my macbook, through an usb-c to usb-a adapter, to a usb-a to micro b adapter, to the Raspberry Pi Pico W. I have tested the connection using leds, buttons & buzzers, and it works fine. I still do not know how to display images on the display though.

You may have better luck and more responses on Raspberry pi StackExchange
